# Getting a list of all AWS services with their description

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a way to list all the AWS services with a short description similar to the one found on the AWS website. I was able to find this [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113718/aws-services-list-and-bulk-pricing-api) from the bulk pricing API however there are differenceswith the services listed in the website (The file lists 100 services while the website lists 144 product).

I need each service with a short description and a way to map it to it's pricing info. What I am asking is why there is a difference between the API and the website and if there is a better way to find all AWS services without having to rely on the website.

Comment: The definition of a "service" is a bit difficult. For example, Amazon EBS is disk storage, but it can only be used with Amazon EC2 instances. So, does it qualify as a "service" unto itself? That's why you might find it hard to create a definitive list of AWS services. What do you wish to do with this list? We might be able to offer an answer if we knew more of your use-case.